# Why textbox name and id affect the border of table in html on IE and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

[image]

This problem only happens on IE and Firefox. There is no problem on Chrome. All of the following `name` values will break the table border - any idea why?

`name = "searchvalue"`

`name = "s-val"`

`name = "sVal"`

Code :

```
<input type="text" name="sval" id="sval1" size="30" value="ss" />
```

Comment: What is your underlying CSS? There might be CSS that is mapped to that ID and Chrome will automatically render a border for textboxes.

Comment: There is no css refer the id and name of textbox. I assign name and id of textbox is just for testing the affect of table border. I want to know why name and id can affect the table border.

Comment: Please strip your code down to the relevant parts. Or even better, have a look at firebug. It will probably show you exactly where your problem is.

Comment: a) there's no reason so there must be something in your code doing this but b) I'm looking at the full size version of your image and see no difference in what you're pointing to.

Comment: @j08691 a)I also guess that there must be something in my code doing this, that's why i create this question. b) full version of my image is at http://2aek.com/textbox-table.jpg

Comment: @DennisTraub Thanks for suggesting me to use firebug. I did try it, it show the code `#predictad_table th, td { border: 0;}` on the file **mclassic.css**. But I cannot see the file in my folder. And firebug show me the location of the file at http://static.app.widdit.com/css/skins/mclassic.css so I guess it is firefox browser build in default css? May I know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

static.app.widdit.com/css/skins/mclassic.css seems to be part of a toolbar.

see: http://widdit.com/

try uninstalling the toolbar